# How could I enable YouTube Content ID API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

According to [What is the YouTube Content ID API?](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/), comes from YouTube official page, only a Youtube partner can see YouTube Contend ID API in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com). However, I have become a YouTube partner but still cannot see the YouTube Content ID API from the console. Could anyone tell me what's the root cause? Thanks!